# How to change li to input type=text and save the new value?

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing this project to school from 'https://randomuser.me/api/'.
clicking on btn a new user will present in a bootstrap card with edit and delete buttons.
every user have list (li) with:
Gender, name, email and more.

clicking on the gender value need to change the li to input(type="text") and clicking on edit need to save the change.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/NV7i1ZiiM5SSdRZ2yJyT?p=preview

Comment: Please click the `<>` button in the editor and create a [mcve] - there is a reason you were not allowed to save the link to plunker

Comment: so it seems the click on gender works, what do you mean by "save" to where?

Comment: Please provide us with some code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I managed to add new input but now i need to click on edit and remove the input and leave only the new li. I know its a json and when refreshing the page it will all disappear . plnkr.co/edit/NV7i1ZiiM5SSdRZ2yJyT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Here is your required solution:

add the below code to your js:

```
 $('body').on('click','.edituser' ,function(){
      $( ".editing" ).each(function() {
        var input = $('<a class="edit" href="#">'+$(this).val()+'</a>');
            $(this).replaceWith(input);
      });
    })
```

**What it does:**

- This will remove all your text boxes and make them to be displayed as `li` when you click on `edit` button.

[**Here is a working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/8l3c8wnWvs0y4XmzHg2L?p=preview)

Comment: checked the plunker? that is your requirement roght?

Comment: you can accept and vote my answer, if you find it useful. :-)